# how to remove login Widget everypage page in localhost.?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, customer, login

In Magento if we are working with the custom theme then the most common problem comes that all the page title displays “Customer Login” for every pages. Even it is not display the Home Page title which we have set into the admin, it only displays the “Customer Login”.

Comment: are you developing custom theme? or else contact your theme provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a shot in the dark here and say that you have a mini-login for on all the pages.
This mini-login form is added via the layout files like this:

```
<block type="customer/form_login" name="some-name-here" template="some/template/here.phtml "/>
```

If that's true, then the problem comes from the `type="customer/form_login"`.
The block that gets instantiated is `Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login` that contains this method

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Login'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

This method is called before the html is rendered and it sets the page title to `Customer Login`.
To overcome this, you need to create your custom block in your custom module that behaves like the login block but does not set the page title.

So create a module. Let's call it `StackExchange_Customer` with the following files:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Customer.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Customer />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Customer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Customer>
    </modules> 
</config>
<global>
    <blocks>
         <stackexchange_customer>
             <class>StackExchange_Customer_Block</class>
         </stackexchange_customer>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Customer/Block/Form/Login.php` - the new login form

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_Customer_Block_Form_Login extends Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login
{
    protected function _prepareLayout() 
    {
         return $this;
    }
}
```

then you need to change in the layout the line

```
<block type="customer/form_login"....
```

to

```
<block type="stackexchange_customer/form_login" ...
```